# JS Object Destructuring with Filter

Tags: javascript, filter, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have an object of objects I want to filter via the value of a key in the objects. For example, my object looks like:

```
const Financials = {
  xxxxx: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 2000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2015
  },
  zzzz: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  },
  aaaa: {
    creditid: "bbbb",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  }
};
```

I want to be able to filter the object by creditid. For example, I want to return an object that contains all the objects that have a creditid of "yyyy".

```
var { creditid: "yyyy" } = Financials;
```

And the result would look like:

```
{
  xxxxx: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 2000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2015
  },
  zzzz: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  }
}
```

Is this possible using destructuring?

Comment: `Is this possible using destructuring?` - I don't think so. Do you want to deep copy the object or not copy the contained objects? I assume editing the original `Financials` is not intended as it is `const`.

Comment: I would want to edit the original. I am trying to update/edit the objects that have a matching key/value pair for creditid. I thought destructuring might be a clean way to attempt it.

Comment: `I am trying to update/edit the objects that have a matching key/value pair for creditid` - is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as destructuring goes, I don't know that this can be done, simply because destructuring works more like `.map()` than `.filter()`. However, you can actually do this pretty easily with the `.reduce()` function, like so:

```js
const Financials = {
  xxxxx: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 2000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2015
  },
  zzzz: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  },
  aaaa: {
    creditid: "bbbb",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  }
};

var filtered = Object.keys(Financials).reduce((res, key) => {
  if (Financials[key].creditid === "yyyy") {
    res[key] = Financials[key]
  }
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to iterate through each property of Financials, as follows:

```
const Financials = {
  xxxxx: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 2000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: '12 / 31 / 2015'
  },
  zzzz: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: '12 / 31 / 2016'
  },
  aaaa: {
    creditid: "bbbb",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: '12 / 31 / 2016'
  }
};

var resultFinancials = {};

for (var financial in Financials) {
    if (Financials.hasOwnProperty(financial)) {
        if(Financials[financial] && Financials[financial].creditid =='yyyy' ){
            resultFinancials[financial] = Financials[financial];
        }
    }
}

console.log(resultFinancials)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just filter the objects entries, and then map it back to new object

```js
const Financials = {
  xxxxx: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 2000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2015
  },
  zzzz: {
    creditid: "yyyy",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  },
  aaaa: {
    creditid: "bbbb",
    aggRevs: 1000,
    aggexpenses: 1000,
    dateOf: 12 / 31 / 2016
  }
};

let arr    = Object.entries(Financials).filter( set => set[1].creditid === "yyyy");
let result = Object.assign(...arr.map(d => ({[d[0]]: d[1]})))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height: 100%!important}
```